# Qt signal slot cv::Mat unable to read memory access violation

Tags: qt, opencv, signals-slots, access-violation, memory-access

I have a Microsoft visual studio application that is grabbing frames from cameras and I am trying to display those frames in a Qt application. I am doing some processing with the frames using OpenCV, so the frames are Mat objects. I use QThreads to parallelize the application. I am getting a Access Violation reading location when I try to emit a Mat signal from my CameraThread class.

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow window;
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "main_window.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    // create a horizontal widget
    main_layout = new QVBoxLayout;

    QHBoxLayout* row1 = new QHBoxLayout;
    QHBoxLayout* row2 = new QHBoxLayout;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        camera_array[i] = new CameraWidget(i);
        if (i < 4)
            row1->addWidget(camera_array[i]);
        else
            row2->addWidget(camera_array[i]);
    }

    main_layout->addLayout(row1);
    main_layout->addLayout(row2);

    // make the central widget the main layout window
    central = new QWidget();
    central->setLayout(main_layout);
    setCentralWidget(central);
}
```

camerawidget.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "camera_widget.h"

CameraWidget::CameraWidget(int id)
{
    camera_id = id;

    qRegisterMetaType<cv::Mat>("cv::Mat");

    current_frame = cv::imread("camera_1.png");

    thread = new CameraThread(camera_id);
    QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(renderFrame(cv::Mat)), this, SLOT(updateFrame(cv::Mat)));
    thread->start();

}

CameraWidget::~CameraWidget()
{
    qDebug("camera widget destructor");
    thread->wait(5000);
}

// initializeGL() function is called just once, before paintGL() is called.
void CameraWidget::initializeGL()
{
    qglClearColor(Qt::black);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 480.0f, 640.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glGenTextures(3, &texture);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 0, 480.0f, 640.0f, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

void CameraWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 480.0f, 640.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    current_frame_i = QImage(current_frame.data, current_frame.cols, current_frame.rows, current_frame.cols * 3, QImage::Format_RGB888);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    // ******************************
    // getting access violation here
    // ******************************   
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 480.0f, 640.0f, 0.0f, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, current_frame.ptr());

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex2i(0, 640.0f);
        glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex2i(0, 0);
        glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex2i(480.0f, 0);
        glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex2i(480.0f, 640.0f);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

void CameraWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    // setup viewport, projection etc.
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 480.0f, 640.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void CameraWidget::updateFrame(cv::Mat image)
{
    current_frame = image;
    update();
}
```

camerathread.cpp

```
CameraThread::CameraThread(int id) 
{
    camera_q = new bounded_frame_queue(50);

}

void CameraThread::run()
{
    cv::Mat image;
    while (true) {
        if (!camera_q->empty()) {
            image = camera_q->pop();
            if (!image.empty())
                emit renderFrame(image);
        }
        else {
            msleep(1);
        }
    }

}
```

When I emit renderFrame from the camerathread.cpp, I get an access violation reading location. I cannot read the current_frame.ptr() value in camerawidget.cpp.

Can someone direct me on how I can fix this issue?

Comment: what is `bounded_frame_queue`? Is it thread-safe? where is it filled with images?

Comment: bounded_frame_queue is queue that i fill with images. It is filled with images in a callback function that is thread safe. I bound this queue with 50 images

Comment: so .pop() .empty() and .push_back (or sth.) are thread-safe, e.g. secured with some kind of mutex or sth? Where can I get information about the class `bounded_frame_queue`?

Comment: I have them all thread-safe with locks. Using boost library to do this.

Comment: did you try filling the queue once in advance with loaded working images to reduce error sources (e.g. if the camera produces some erroneous images or something)? Did you try rendering images without multi-threading using the same signals/slots to avoid another error source?

Comment: I did fill the queue and I am able to use cv::imshow(image) to display the image before I emit renderframe(image) in camerathread.cpp and it is able to display the image, although it does take a 1 second to display it properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148794/discussion-between-pete-and-micka).

Answer (score 3):

What I see is happenning:

1. You get an image from queue. As per [OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aed1f81fe7efaacc2bd95149cdfa34302):

   Mat& cv::Mat::operator= (   const Mat &     m   )

> Assigned, right-hand-side matrix. Matrix assignment is an O(1)
>   operation. This means that no data is copied but the data is shared
>   and the reference counter, if any, is incremented. Before assigning
>   new data, the old data is de-referenced via Mat::release .

2. Then you pass it as `cv::Mat image` (by value) when emitting signal. The [copy constructor](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a294eaf8a95d2f9c7be19ff594d06278e) again doesn't copy any data:

> Array that (as a whole or partly) is assigned to the constructed
>   matrix. No data is copied by these constructors. Instead, the header
>   pointing to m data or its sub-array is constructed and associated with
>   it. The reference counter, if any, is incremented. So, when you modify
>   the matrix formed using such a constructor, you also modify the
>   corresponding elements of m . If you want to have an independent copy
>   of the sub-array, use Mat::clone() .

3. Your data pointers are queued on UI thread
4. You get/try-get new frame triggering release from p.1
5. Your queued slot is executed and crashes...

Suggestion: I haven't worked much with it, but it seems something like `cv::Mat::clone` to make a deep copy is what you need, to prevent release of memory before it would be used by UI thread.

Or possibly it would be enough to define image right when you pop it from queue:

```
cv::Mat image = camera_q->pop();
```