# How to extract feature from QImage?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

This may be a silly question. As still I am new in Qt programming, this question always arises in mind.

In OpenCV, there are a few feature detection techniques like SIFT, SURF, ORB, BRIEF which extract features from two `Mat` images and draw lines between these two Mat images using `cv::drawMatches` function, if any matches are found.

Are there any function in Qt GUI, using which matching lines can also be drawn between two `QImage`? Or how can I use those feature detection techniques to extract features from `QImage`?

I appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no CV functionality in Qt.

Comment: Given to `QImage`, you should stitch them in a third, larger image. And then draw a line on this third image.

Comment: Draw in OpenCV, then copy to QImage

Comment: Check if this is useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158740/efficient-integration-of-qt-and-opencv

Comment: Do you want to 1) do some computer vision processing (like extract some feature) or 2) do some graphical stuff? For 1) work with `Mat` and OpenCV and then just convert the result into a QImage for diplaying. For 2) don't even bother to use OpenCV